# How to correctly jack up the front of a 2005 Mazda 6

Tags: mazda-6, jack

I did a fair amount of research before trying to jack up the front of this car. I watched some videos of people jacking up similar (but not identical cars), and I pulled this image from the web:

[image]

Nothing matched exactly, but I thought I had a good enough idea of where to place the jack and began lifting the car.

Half way through the lift, the jack suddenly moved sideways. It didn't lose contact with the car or drop it, but something had suddenly shifted. Concerned, I immediately lowered the car and saw that I had bent the piece of metal I was lifting against.

ಠ_ಠ

[image]

So what damage have I done here? Is this fixable? Is it safe to ignore?

And most importantly, what's the correct way to jack up the front of a 2005 Mazda 6, since what I did here is clearly not it?

Comment: Did you rely on the jack’s own plate or did you put some type of spacer/support on the jack plate? If not, then those plates can often slip...

Comment: @SolarMike - I used the jack's own plate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I did some more thorough searching, this time more sharply motivated to find the correct information given my previous mistake, and found [an upload of the 2004 Mazda 6 Workshop Manual](http://www.6crew.com/forum/showthread.php?19623-MAZDA-6-FULL-WORKSHOP-MANUAL). The 2005 model is, I understand, very similar to the 2004 model, so the information inside should be just as applicable.

Here's the relevant page from the manual:

[image: Jacking Positions]

And here are some pictures of the correct jacking point, with the jack applied to it:

[image: 2005 Mazda 6 Front Jacking Point]

[image: Front of 2005 Mazda 6 Jacked Up]

And after some more digging in the manual, I also found the name of the part I damaged--it's the rear half of the front crossmember. I identified it by the 3 oval-shaped holes:

[image: Front Suspension Breakdown]

I hope this information will keep someone else working on this or a very similar model car from making my mistake.